# query with multiple-result subquery not working with jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've been working on this specific problem now for a few days and can't find any solutions. Thus, here I am.

**The situation:**

- Table1 lists all JBoss on the system
- Table2 pictures a 1:n relation of JBoss and JBoss since any given JBoss can have one or more JBoss it 'speaks' to.
- I have a Java servlet with JDBC to connect to the database and issue queries and .jsp pages to display the results

**EDIT:**

What do I intend to do with the query: My servlet is trying to display all the information connected to a given jboss. The user selects a jboss from the list of jboss names from a jsp page. Then the query is executed and the error occurs.

**EDIT2:**

Changing the query to inner subselect to a `where in` results in the same error when testing the applet

**EDIT4:**

Tried creating a view with the query as script, then trying to get all entries from the created view with `select * from vtest` without success.

**The Problem:**

When I try to run the following `select` with the servlet, it results in ORA-01427. If I run this statement in `Toad for Oracle` I get the desired result.

```
select * from table1 where number in (
select jboss2 from table2 where jboss1 = (
select number from table1 where name = 'nam1'))
```

**The Question:**
Is there something I'm missing with the query? Is it possible that `jdbc` can't handle subqueries with multiple rows as result, even if the query itself is correct?

Table 1:

```
+--------+------+-----------+
| Number | Name | values... |
+--------+------+-----------+
| 000001 | nam1 | vals1     |
| 000002 | nam2 | vals2     |
| 000003 | nam3 | vals3     |
+--------+------+-----------+
```

Table 2:

```
+--------+--------+
| JBoss1 | JBoss2 |
+--------+--------+
| 000001 | 000002 |
| 000001 | 000003 |
| 000002 | 000003 |
+--------+--------+
```

Result in Toad/Desired result:

```
+--------+------+-----------+
| Number | Name | values... |
+--------+------+-----------+
| 000002 | nam2 | vals2     |
| 000003 | nam3 | vals3     |
+--------+------+-----------+
```

**EDIT3:**

Relevant Java classes. Omitted nonrelevant queries.

```
class QuickInfoAction implements Action{

    @Override
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement prep = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Map<String,String> queries = Queries.getInfoQueries(request);

        try {
            conn = DatabaseConnector.getConnection();
            Map<String, Result> res = new HashMap<String, Result>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: queries.entrySet()) {
                prep = conn.prepareStatement(entry.getValue()); 
                rs = prep.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()) {
                    res.put(entry.getKey(), ResultSupport.toResult(rs));
                }       
            }

            request.setAttribute("results", res);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ActionException(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
                prep.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ActionException(e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }

        return "results";
    }

}


public static Map<String, String> getInfoQueries(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String jboss_res = "select jboss.name, jboss.port, jboss.apache_nummer, jboss.bere_mandant_id, "
            + "maschine.name as maschine, maschine.ip_adresse "
            + "from jboss "
            + "inner join maschine on jboss.maschine_nummer = maschine.nummer "
            + "where jboss.name = '" + request.getParameter("jboss") + "'";

    String jboss_db = "select datenbank.nummer, datenbank.name, db_schema.name as schema "
            + "from datenbank "
            + "inner join db_schema on datenbank.db_schema_nummer = db_schema.nummer "
            + "where datenbank.nummer = ("
                + "select datenbank_nummer "
                + "from jboss_datenbank "
                + "where jboss_nummer = ("
                    + "select nummer "
                    + "from jboss "
                    + "where name = '" + request.getParameter("jboss") + "'))";

    String jboss_tux = "select tuxedo.*, datenbank.name as datenbank, db_schema.name as schema "
            + "from tuxedo, datenbank,db_schema "
            + "where tuxedo.nummer = ("
                + "select tuxedo_nummer "
                + "from jboss "
                + "where name = '" + request.getParameter("jboss") + "') "
            + "and datenbank.nummer = ("
                + "select datenbank_nummer "
                + "from tuxedo_datenbank "
                + "where tuxedo_nummer = tuxedo.nummer) "
            + "and db_schema.nummer = ("
                + "select db_schema_nummer "
                + "from datenbank "
                + "where nummer = ("
                    + "select datenbank_nummer "
                    + "from tuxedo_datenbank "
                    + "where tuxedo_nummer = tuxedo.nummer))";
    String jboss_corr = "select * from jboss where nummer in ("
                + "select jboss_nummer_2 from jboss_corr where jboss_nummer_1 in ("
                + "select nummer from jboss where name = '" + request.getParameter("jboss") + "'))";

    Map<String, String> queries = new HashMap<String,String>();
    queries.put("jboss", jboss_res);
    queries.put("datenbank", jboss_db);
    queries.put("tuxedo", jboss_tux);
    queries.put("corr", jboss_corr);

return queries;
```

Error Message

```
03.07.2017 11:49:29,863 +0200 WARN  [at.itsv.ta2mig.jdbc.TA2MigOracleJDBCConnection] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)    ORA-01427: Unterabfrage für eine Zeile liefert mehr als eine Zeile

03.07.2017 11:49:29,864 +0200 INFO  [stdout] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)    error executing action

03.07.2017 11:49:29,864 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)    dbgr.exception.ActionException: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@46708550

03.07.2017 11:49:29,864 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at dbgr.action.QuickInfoAction.execute(QuickInfoAction.java:43)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,864 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at dbgr.servlet.ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:28)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,865 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at dbgr.servlet.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:39)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,865 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,865 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,865 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,865 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,865 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,866 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,867 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,867 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)

03.07.2017 11:49:29,867 +0200 ERROR [stderr] (hs0903 http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: This would appear to be the problem: `select number from table1 where name = 'nam1'` ... are you sure your underlying data is the same in both places?

Comment: @harlequin: Would you please tell what is the exact requirement behind your query ? What you are trying to achieve via the query ? Possibly your query itself can be simplified and integrated easily with java.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with the underlying data and why this `select` would be the problem?

Comment: I am not telling existing query would be the problem. I am just asking that what is the exact requirement of your query ? Is it like get details of all JBoss with which JBoss having name=nam1 speaks to ?

Comment: The subquery I pointed is returning more than one record, if the error message is to be believed.  You need to find out why this is happening.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal I added the intent of the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I checked the results and the statement you pointed out returns only one value. `select jboss2 from table2 where jboss1 = ...` returns more than one value

Comment: @harlequin Yes but this should be OK for `where in`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried changing the inner select to a `where in` and the result is the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should show us the relevant Java code as well.  I get the feeling you are not running what you think you are.

Comment: Can you share your jdbc code and exact exception message ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added the relevant java code. Maybe the problem lies there. All other queries are functioning and the query in question works IF there is only one result

Comment: You still haven't added your exception message. Moreover you mentioned that you have omitted non-relevant queries but it is possible that any one of those queries are generating error for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Another query also returned more than one result. This query was not designed to do so, thus failed. It was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

seem you need  a wher e in for the inner subselect too

```
select * from table1 where number in (
  select jboss2 from table2 where jboss1 in (
    select number from table1 where name = 'nam1'))
```

Comment: I've tried changing the inner select like that to no avail. It still results in the same error

Comment: check better .. the error  ORA-01427.  is for returning more then a rows and th in clasue must solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the query with where-in doesn't work for you, but here is a query where the second subquery is replaced by a join:

```sql
select * from table1 where number in (
  select jboss2 from table2
  join table1 on table2.jboss1 = table1.number
    and table1.name = 'nam1'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the query version but unfortunately I still get the same error.